# Excel conditional formatting based on list of cell references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to mark the changed cells in a new version of an Excel file. Using the `Compare files` functionality of Excel 2013, I can get a list of changed cells:

[image]

Now I'd like to use that list of cell references to mark the corresponding cells in the Excel sheet through `conditional formatting`.

[image]

How do I do that? (There are hundreds of cell references, so I do not want to do it manually.)

Comment: @pnuts: I just added the cell references in the text. Now updated with a table instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try putting this as a formula into Conditional Formatting:-

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"$",""),Changes,0)))
```

where Changes is the range where you have your list of cells that don't match. I'm assuming that your list of changes do not have $ signs in them.

Here is a much more concise version of the formula as explained in the comment below.

```
=MATCH(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4),changes,0)
```

Comment: `ADDRESS` will give a relative formula with `4` given as the third parameter.  This removes the need for `SUBSTITUTE`.  That would look something like: `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4),changes,0)))`.  You can also use `ISNUMBER` instead of `NOT(ISERROR(` but that's really a matter of preference.  That is a moot point though because conditional formatting will use the number as `TRUE` and the error as `FALSE` so you can just use: `=MATCH(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4),changes,0)`.